# ActionBarSherlock Problems continue using 4.0 book

Tags: android, commonsware

[image]Now using the 4.0 book.

I created a new project from T5 - progress...

Attached the "Android Support Package" as per instructions on page 214. (need to be running eclipse

as an administrator for this to work on windows 7)

Downloaded ActionBarSherlock and placed the \library directory on my Desktop renaming the directory

to ActionBarSherlock as per instructions on page 217.

Followed the instructions on page 218 creating a second project from Existing code navigating to the

ActionBarSherlock directory on my desktop.

Hit finish and got: "Marker id 2320 not found."

Clicked off that error dialog and saw the the new ActionBarSherlock project had > 100 errors.

Checked the API level and saw that it is set to 15.

Then I did a project > Clean as instructed if errors exist.

Set both projects to compiler level 1.6 and did another clean build on both projects.

100 Errors remain.

Thanks, Gary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To quote myself:

> If you are still getting errors, and an examination of the ActionBarSherlock code
>   indicates that the complaints are about @Override annotations on methods that are implementing an interface, rather than truly overriding a superclass method, you
>   need to adjust your Eclipse compiler compliance level to be 1.6, instead of 1.5. Even
>   if you already did this at the workspace level, you may need to do it at a project
>   level.

(see Version 4.0, page 218)

Comment: I did that (my second to last line)... "Set both projects to compiler level 1.6 and did another clean build on both projects." But all is well - deleted problem project and imported from commonsware github instead of using the JakeWharton stuff and all worked well.

Comment: @user1058647: "I did that (my second to last line)" -- then it didn't take for some reason, because that's almost certainly the source of the errors shown in your screenshot. Anyway, glad to hear that it is working!